# Make div a link, differences between two codes

Tags: html, css, href

Ι want to make a `div` that contains images and text a fully square link. So far, I found the following codes:

```
<a href="">
    <img src="">
    Some text
</a>
```

with:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

while the 2nd one is the exact same as above but with an outer `div`:

```
<div>
    <a href="">
        <img src="">
        Some text
    </a>
</div>
```

Are they any differences? What should I choose? Ty

Comment: 1st option: You are using the display:block to convert a tag (inline tag) to block tag.
2nd option: you are using DIV tag ( block tag) so you don't need to use display:block

Comment: Voting to close as this will be opinion based. Do what gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you want, but I'm not sure if I follow if you want to be able to click on the div and do something or you just want a `<div>` around everything.

If the later, give this a try. You'll need to adjust the height/width and such to fit your needs, but this should get you started.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        Some text
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

div > a {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    div {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #ddd;
      padding: 25px 0px;
    }
    
    div a {
      background-color: #000;
      display: block;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    div a img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain" /> Some text
    </a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Totally depends upon the usage. Something you can control with parent div is alignment.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" /></a>
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" /></a>
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" /></a>
</div>
```